# Table Styling not being applied

Tags: css, html-table, accordion

I'm creating an table and have styled it accordingly on CSS. The code works (https://jsfiddle.net/he16Lxz9/) however when it's nested within an accordion, the styling disappears (http://firebird.sheridanc.on.ca/~ixd487/hire%20brighter/co-op.html)

HTML

```
 <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Length of Internship</td>
                        <td>4, 8, 12, 16 Months</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Paid or Unpaid</td>
                        <td>Paid</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Weekly Commitment</td>
                        <td>Minimum 35hrs/week</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Start Date</td>
                        <td>September, January, or May</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Contact</td>
                        <td>Email: <a href="mailto: engcoop@mcmaster.ca"> engcoop@mcmaster.ca</a> <br> Phone: (905)-525-9140 ext. 24674</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

CSS

```
table {
width: 100%;
border-collapse: collapse;
font-family: 'Barlow Semi Condensed', sans-serif;}

/* Zebra striping */

tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
background: #eee;}

th {
background: #333;
color: white;
font-weight: bold;}

td,
th {
padding: 6px;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you have the css code in the other website? (the one with accordion)?

Comment: Add a class to the table, and then modify your CSS to use the table class in the class name chaining. That way your selectors are not global.

Comment: Can you turn the webpage into a [mcve]?